# Is it a good practice to code-sign executable JARs of desktop applications?

Tags: java, jar, code-signing, executable-jar, jarsigner

I have developed a desktop software in JAVA which will be launched by a BAT or a VBS file which, in turn, will run the Executable JAR with "javaw -jar" command.

I have a code-signing certificate that I use for the installer. Would it be advisable to sign the executable JAR as well?

It is important to sign the installer to avoid the Windows Unknown Publisher message. But why would it be important to sign an executable JAR?

Comment: If you have a code-signing certificate signed by a real CA, you should consider using Java Web Start to distribute your application.  Web Start is an installer/updater that works on all platforms.  The only additional effort needed on your part is writing a short XML file which describes the application and its installation options.

Comment: I've suffered through all the changes surrounding Java Web Start and it is just not worth the effort. 
You can now create a stand-alone executable directly and that is good enough for most cases.

Comment: @JochenBedersdorfer I was creating standalone executables in 1997. It is JWS that is newer.

Comment: @JochenBedersdorfer I am aware of no changes, other than stricter security.  (It used to be the case that unsigned and self-signed .jar files could run in the sandbox without a site exception, but no longer.)  Stand-alone executables are huge, for obvious reasons, and they cannot benefit from updated Java versions containing things like, well, security fixes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you are currently distributing your application, you don’t need to sign the .jar file.

A Java program, like an executable program, is capable of doing substantial harm to a computer.  Most technically aware people know better than to run a strange .exe file found on a web site.  Java applications are no different.

So if the Java program is something the user downloads from a web site, it should be signed.  In fact, if it’s distributed using Java’s standard installation/automatic update tool, Java Web Start, it *must* be signed with a code-signing certificate (unless you want to try to guide non-technical users through adding a “site exception” in the Java Control Panel).

A signed .jar file doesn’t guarantee the Java application will not harm the user’s computer, of course.  It just guarantees that the owner of the certificate has been verified, so if the program does cause harm, the user knows whom to blame.

If you have a code-signing certificate signed by a real CA, you should consider signing your .jar with it, and distributing it using Java Web Start rather than a script.  Web Start is an installer/updater that works on all platforms.  The only additional effort needed on your part is writing a short XML file which describes the application and its installation options.

Answer (score 1):

There is no harm to sign your JAR file with the Code Signing certificate.

- If you have not signed the JAR file, and when a user try to download that file, there will a browser alert message during download process says "This file type can potentially harmful to your computer".

But if you have signed the JAR file with the Code Signing certificate, there will no alert message. This will also indicates the Software/App code and Owner both are verified and trusted.

AS you said, you own the code signing certificate, I would like to suggest you to sign the JAR file.

Check the below image for "Error message if the file is not Encrypted with Code Signing".

[image: Error message if the file is not Encrypted with Code Signing]